# TCP ACK time varies on Linux and Windows for SSL

Tags: ssl, tcp

I need to send a secured request using Java(jre1.8.0_65) on my Windows PC. 
I used the below code to configure my certs and key factory.

```java
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

InputStream ins = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("certs/tester1024.pfx");
ks.load(ins, "1234".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SUNX509");
kmf.init(ks, "1234".toCharArray());
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

URL obj = new URL(httpURL);

HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
if (connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
    ((HttpsURLConnection)connection)
    .setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
}
```

It works well but there is strange behavior with response time. On windows it takes more time; on Linux it's faster.

When I see the Wireshark packets, came to know that ACK for Client hello is receiving very late almost after 200ms (actually after receiving the Server Hello).

Both the Linux and Windows PCs are connected to the same Access Point. I am running the same Java application on both OS. I attached the Windows Wireshark log also.

Any help is really appreciated.

[WireShark log on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68pZb.png)

[WireShark log on linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mj57a.png)

Comment: Why do you care? You got the ServerHello, that's all you need, or rather all that SSL needs. The delayed ACk only affects removal of pending data from the socket send buffer, but during an SSL handshake there isn't any.

Comment: yes ... I need to worry because performance is important .. my application on the PC sends  CONTROL commands to some Embedded devices .. so total response time important for the User experience.

Comment: ACK time doesn't have anything to do with the user experience, or very little. Do you actually have a real performance problem of any kind?

Comment: yes, When user sends some action to the device and if it executed very fast(expected is around 600ms) , as per our study its good seamless experience for the user.. Hence need to understand why ACK is delayed on windows.